# query copying part of info from one table to another

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables. the first is merchants and the other is sheet 1, both of them have the columns 'id' and 'name' (sheet 1 is an excel import and contains some of the id's and their respective names, where as merchants only has id's and the names are all blank).

what i want to do is where the id's in the two tables match, write the name from sheet1 for that id to merchants name.

i started with an insert into, but this just inserted all the names where the id's matched as new rows with id's of 0. So i clearly need to use an update statement. but i cant get it to work with something like:

```
UPDATE merchents
SET name = sheet1.name
FROM sheet1
WHERE id=sheet.id
```

I think i might need an inner join, but im not sure, my sql is not that good.

```
UPDATE merchents
SET name = sheet1.name
FROM sheet1 s INNER JOIN merchents m
ON s.id = m.id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE m
SET m.name = s.name 
FROM sheet1 s INNER JOIN merchents m 
ON s.id = m.id
```

Comment: Hey, first tnk u for ur help, i tested the last two lines with a select * and it works, but when i try use the whole thing i get an error

Comment: UPDATE merchents 
    SET name = (SELECT s.name 
                          FROM sheet1 s 
                         WHERE  s.id = merchents .id )

Answer (score 0):

`id` should be unique or primary key. Try this `INSERT`:

```
INSERT INTO merchents SELECT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE merchents.name=sheet1.name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Update merchents
Set merchents.name = sheet1.name
From sheet1, merchents
Where sheet1.id = merchents.id;
```

This is another alternative other than using join statements